# Effect of adding a constant to the torsion of a 3D curve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

Let $\gamma$ be an arc-length parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let say I add a constant to the torsion of $\gamma$ and let $\widetilde{\gamma}$ be the curve associated to the curvature of $\gamma$ and this new torsion. Is there an easy way to characterize $\widetilde{\gamma}$ in terms of $\gamma$? In other words, is there a map that links $\gamma$ to $\widetilde{\gamma}$?

Comment: For example $\gamma(t) = (\sin t, \cos t)$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = (\sin t + c_1, \cos t + c_2)$. Just to understand your qeustion. Are you asking how these curves are related to each other?

Comment: @aGer your two curves have the same torsion, zero. I would like to know what happens to a curve when its torsion is changed by the addition of a constant.